# Automatic conversion of function arguments between related template classes

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, type-conversion

Suppose I have a pair of related templates, and I want to automatically convert arguments to some function from one of them to the other. How can I achieve that?

```
template<int a> struct bar;

template<int a, int b> struct foo {
  operator bar<a> const (); // operator-based conversion
};

template<int a> struct bar : public foo<a, a> {
  bar() { }
  template<int b> bar(const foo<a, b>&) { } // constructor-based conversion
};

template<int a, int b> foo<a, b>::operator bar<a> const () { return bar<a>(); }

template<int a> void f(bar<a> x, bar<a> y) { }

int main() {
  bar<1> x;
  foo<1, 2> y;
  f(x, y);
}
```

To this, gcc 4.8.3 says:

```
template argument deduction/substitution failed: ‘foo<1, 2>’ is not derived from ‘bar<a>’
```

The intention would be that the second argument to `f` gets converted from `foo<1,2>` to `bar<1>` via some code which I control. But apparently neither the templated conversion constructor nor the non-templated cast operator work for this case. Is there any idiom I can use to make this work?

Comment: I think it's cause `void f()` is a template function; implicit parameter conversions are illegal for template functions.  Try `void f(bar<1> x, bar<1> y)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Template argument deduction requires exact matches (as Xeo points out in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25020680/automatic-conversion-of-function-arguments-between-related-template-classes#comment38909796_25020852), a single standard conversion sequence (Clause 4) will be applied, if needed), and user defined conversions are not considered. So it fails to deduce the template argument `a` from the second argument to `f()` (which is of type `foo<1,2>`). One way around this is to turn the second parameter type into a non-deduced context. Then `a` will be deduced from the first argument alone, and your code will compile.

```
#include <functional>
#include <memory>

template<typename T>
struct identity
{
  using type = T;
};

template<int a> struct bar;

template<int a, int b> struct foo {
  operator bar<a> const (); // operator-based conversion
};

template<int a> struct bar : public foo<a, a> {
  bar() { }
  template<int b> bar(const foo<a, b>&) { } // constructor-based conversion
};

template<int a, int b> foo<a, b>::operator bar<a> const () { return bar<a>(); }

template<int a> void f(bar<a> x, typename identity<bar<a>>::type y) { }
//                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
int main() {
  bar<1> x;
  foo<1, 2> y;
  f(x, y);
}
```

[Live demo](http://ideone.com/0gYc2v)

Comment: The live demo is small enough that you could probably just inline it in your post.

Comment: "Exact" only insofar that only a single Standard Conversion Sequence applies.

Answer (score 2):

When you perform template argument deduction on two or more arguments, both arguments must match either exactly, via a qualification conversion or via a base class conversion (14.8.2.1p4 **[temp.deduct.call]**).

You can suppress argument deduction on one argument using a type transformation:

```
template<class T> struct identity { using type = T; };
template<class T> using identity_t = typename identity<T>::type;
template<int a> void f(bar<a> x, identity_t<bar<a>> y) { }
```

Comment: A single Standard Conversion Sequence is performed.

Comment: @Xeo I'm pretty sure [temp.deduct.call] applies; where does the standard conversion sequence fit in?

Comment: Ah, it's not exactly an SCS, but basically behaves like one. The subpoints in p4 deal with qualification conversions, and lvalue-to-rvalue applies afterwards, I think. The integral promotions etc don't fit, since there's no promotion target.