# Template argument deduction from lambda

Tags: c++, templates, lambda

I'm attempting to write a function that basically transforms an instance of a class templated on one type to an instance of the same class templated on a second type. I'd like to avoid having to explicitly state the template types when calling the function.

Here's a minimal compilable example of what I'm trying to do:

```
template<class T> class container {};

template <class A, class B, template <class C> class Container>
Container<B> transform(Container<A> c, B(func)(A))
{
  return Container<B>{};
}

int do_something(int in)
{
  return in + 1;
}

int main()
{
  container<int> c{};

  //this one doesn't work:
  //transform(c, [](int in) -> int { return in + 1; });
  //these are fine:
  transform<int, int>(c, [](int in) -> int { return in + 1; });
  transform(c, do_something);

  return 0;
}
```

Uncommenting out the first `transform` call results in compile errors:

Visual Studio 2017:

```
error C2784: 'Container<B> transform(Container<A>,B (__cdecl *)(A))': could not deduce template argument for 'B (__cdecl *)(A)' from 'test::<lambda_afc081691b59f849887abca17e74b763>'
```

Whichever version of g++ coliru.stacked-crooked.com uses by default:

```
main.cpp:4:14: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
main.cpp:18:52: note:   mismatched types 'B (*)(A)' and 'main()::<lambda(int)>'
   transform(c, [](int in) -> int { return in + 1; });
                                                   ^
```

Does this mean that it is not possible for the compiler to deduce the signature of a lambda, even when it has been clearly defined like this?

I know I can rewrite my transform function like this:

```
template <class A, template <class C> class Container, class F>
auto transform(Container<A> c, F func)->Container<decltype(func(A{}))>
{
  return Container<decltype(func(A{}))>{};
}
```

but now the function signature is a little less readable and the error messages I get if I supply an inappropriate function are quite unfriendly. Using a `std::function<B(A)>` doesn't help either.

Is there a way to use the more tightly specified function argument with lambdas and without explicitly adding the template types?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to convert the capture-less lambda into the static function that preforms the operation. That conversion can actually be invoked fairly easily with an application of the unary `+` operator.

```
transform(c, +[](int in) -> int { return in + 1; });
```

Since the closure type of a capture-less lambda has a conversion operator to `ret(*)(params)`, the compiler will invoke it when encountering `+`. That is because you can actually apply a `+` to pointer types.

[[expr.unary.op/7]](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.unary.op#7)

> The operand of the unary + operator shall have arithmetic, unscoped enumeration, **or pointer type and the result is the value of the argument**. Integral promotion is performed on integral or enumeration operands. The type of the result is the type of the promoted operand.

Comment: I had never heard of the `+` trick before. Nifty. Coliru's g++ will accept that just fine, but VS2015 and VS2017 fail with an interesting `'operator +' is ambiguous` error, being unable to distinguish between `<lambda_typedef_cdecl>` and `<lambda_typedef_vectorcall>`, so unfortunately I can't use this trick.

Comment: @Rook - Of course MSVC would reject it... Sorry, I don't know how to get around that.

Comment: since the parameter is a function shouldn't have the conversion of lambda to function pointer happen implicitly?

Comment: @bolov - Not in a deduced context. It's somewhere in the standard, but I'm having trouble finding it at the moment.

Comment: Just found another reference to the same solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25038534/template-type-deduction-with-lambdas?rq=1 Seems like MSVC has been unable to do this for years. Bit disappointing that.

Comment: @bolov - Indeed. But in essence, it's the same principle by which we were all bitten when trying to do [this](https://ideone.com/Kw6JRJ).

Comment: I've marked you as the answer because you've offered what appears to be the only workaround for the problem, even if it didn't work out for me.

Answer (score 2):

`B` and `A` cannot be deduced in `B(func)(A)` from lambda.

You might change your template to be more generic, something like:

```
template <template <typename...> class Container, typename Ts...>
auto transform(const Container<Ts...>& c, F f)
-> Container<std::decay_t<decltype(f(*c.begin())>>
{
    return {};
}
```